# Password Protection not working for Custom B2C Flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom B2C login flow and I have set the "Authentication methods | Password protection" lockout threshold to 5. When I use the flow I am expecting to be locked out after I have 5 failed logins. The first 5 fails are reported as invalid username/password, and I was expecting to get a "account locked" response on the 6th failure, but I just get the invalid username/password response. Why isn't this working as expected?

Comment: You got to be fast, you got to use random passwords, unique each attempt. Each password must have met the password complexity. It’s designed to be triggered by bots, not humans, hence the word “smart” lockout. It’s not a rudimentary counter.

Comment: I answered this question already, did you delete that question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try Password Protection by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management). And it works well.

[image]

Maybe you miss the two details.

**Note:**

1. Entering the same password repeatedly doesn't count as multiple unsuccessful logins.
2. select **Azure AD B2C -> Security**, but not **Azure Active Directory -> Security**

Comment: Ok yes it does work when you follow the rules fromJas Suri above

You got to be fast, you got to use random passwords, unique each attempt. Each password must have met the password complexity. It’s designed to be triggered by bots, not humans, hence the word “smart” lockout. It’s not a rudimentary counter.